# How to fix React Native Agora asynchronous error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, agora.io

I was given this Eslint error:

Assignments to the '_engine' variable from inside React Hook useCallback will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useCallback.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

from this code:

```
  const RtcEngineInit = useCallback(async () => {
    const {appId} = appInit;
    _engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);

    await _engine.enableAudio();

    _engine.addListener('UserOffline', (uid: any, reason: any) => {
      console.log('UserOffline', uid, reason);
      const {peerIds} = appInit;
      setAppInit((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        peerIds: peerIds.filter((id) => id !== uid),
      }));
    });

    _engine.addListener(
      'JoinChannelSuccess',
      (channel: any, uid: any, elapsed: any) => {
        console.log('JoinChannelSuccess', channel, uid, elapsed);

        setAppInit((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          joinSucceed: true,
        }));
      },
    );
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    RtcEngineInit();
  }, [RtcEngineInit]);
```

could someone explain me why this is happening and help me to solve that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, You should not have the RTC Engine inside the render loop. All the statements inside the render loop get executed again. To avoid this. You can have the RTC engine inside a useRef hook.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  let engine = useRef<RtcEngine | null>(null);

  const appid: string = 'APPID';
  const channelName: string = 'channel-x';
  const [joinSucceed, setJoinSucceed] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [peerIds, setPeerIds] = useState<Array<number>>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    /**
     * @name init
     * @description Function to initialize the Rtc Engine, attach event listeners and actions
     */
    async function init() {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        //Request required permissions from Android
        await requestCameraAndAudioPermission();
      }
      engine.current = await RtcEngine.create(appid);
      engine.current.enableVideo();

      engine.current.addListener('UserJoined', (uid: number) => {
        //If user joins the channel
        setPeerIds((pids) =>
          pids.indexOf(uid) === -1 ? [...pids, uid] : pids,
        ); //add peer ID to state array
      });

      engine.current.addListener('UserOffline', (uid: number) => {
        //If user leaves
        setPeerIds((pids) => pids.filter((userId) => userId !== uid)); //remove peer ID from state array
      });

      engine.current.addListener('JoinChannelSuccess', () => {
        //If Local user joins RTC channel
        setJoinSucceed(true); //Set state variable to true
      });
    }
    init();
  }, []);

  
  return <UI />
};

export default App;
```

The full example at:
https://github.com/technophilic/Agora-RN-Quickstart/blob/sdk-v3-ts/src/App.tsx